# How to find out all nested child node of a parent nod?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have this JSTree

[image]

and following code for this tree

```
var data1 = [{
  "id": "W",
  "text": "World",
  "state": { "opened": true },
  "children": [{"text": "Asia"}, 
               {"text": "Africa"}, 
               {"text": "Europe",
                "state": { "opened": false },
                "children": [ "France","Germany","UK" ]
  }]
}];

$('#data').jstree({ 
    core: {
      data: data1, 
      check_callback: false
    }, 
    checkbox: {       

      whole_node : false,
      tie_selection : false 
    },
    plugins: ['checkbox','search']
})
```

What I want is to get all the nested or deep child node of a parent node . How can I do this ?

Comment: can't you get this like `data1[0].id;` ?

Comment: No, suppose if I have selected World as it is a parent node , it has 6 children including nested so how can I get all the children list or length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want is to get all the nested or deep child node of a parent node . How can I do this ?

You need to have a starting node from which to start. Let's assume you listen for the "select_node.jstree" event to get the current selected node.

The main functions you are looking for are [.get_children_dom(node) and .is_leaf(node)](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/).

The full example is:

```
.on('check_node.jstree', function(e, obj) {
    var currentNode = obj.node;
    $('#data').jstree(true).open_all(currentNode);
    var allChildren = $('#data').jstree(true).get_children_dom(currentNode);
    var result = [currentNode.text];
    allChildren.find('li').andSelf().each(function(index, element) {
        if ($('#data').jstree(true).is_leaf(element)) {
            result.push(element.textContent);
        } else {
            var nod = $('#data').jstree(true).get_node(element);
            result.push(nod.text);
        }
    });
    console.log(result.join(', '));
});
```

The full snippet with all the functions is:

```js
var data1 = [{
  "id": "W",
  "text": "World",
  "state": {"opened": true},
  "children": [{"text": "Asia"},
               {"text": "Africa"},
               {
                 "text": "Europe",
                 "state": {"opened": false},
                 "children": ["France", "Germany", "UK"]
               }]
}];

$(function () {
  $('#data').jstree({
    core: {
      data: data1,
      check_callback: false
    },
    checkbox: {

      whole_node: false,
      tie_selection: false
    },
    plugins: ['checkbox', 'search']
  }).on('check_node.jstree.jstree', function(e, obj) {
    var currentNode = obj.node;
    $('#data').jstree(true).open_all(currentNode);
    var allChildren = $('#data').jstree(true).get_children_dom(currentNode);
    var result = [currentNode.text];
    allChildren.find('li').andSelf().each(function(index, element) {
      if ($('#data').jstree(true).is_leaf(element)) {
        result.push(element.textContent);
      } else {
        var nod = $('#data').jstree(true).get_node(element);
        result.push(nod.text);
      }
    });
    console.log(result.join(', '));
  });

  $('#btnClose').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#data').jstree(true).close_all();
  });

  var to = false;
  $('#search').on('input', function(e) {
    if (to) { clearTimeout(to); }
    to = setTimeout(function () {
      var v = $('#search').val();
      $('#data').jstree(true).search(v);
    }, 250);
  });

  $('#btnCheckAll').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#data').jstree(true).check_all();
  });

  $('#btnUnCheckAll').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#data').jstree(true).uncheck_all();
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: red;
  border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>


<label form="search">Products: </label>
<input type="text" value="" id="search" placeholder="Search products">
<div id="divPanel">
    <button id="btnCheckAll">Check All</button><button id="btnUnCheckAll">UnCheck All</button><button id="btnClose">Close</button>
    <div id="data">

        <ul>
            <li>Root node 1
                <ul>
                    <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
                    <li>Child node 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Root node 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but there is a little tweak in the code, instead of using 'select_node' I am using  'check_node', to do something when I click on the checkbox, not on the node .  So how should I get all child and sub-child of a node when I click on particular node

Comment: @code_legend I updated the snippet using 'check_node' instead of 'select_node'. When you check (not uncheck) a node the result array will contain the text of all (current node (child) and sub-child). Run the snippet and see the messages in the snippet console. Let me know in case of problems.

Comment: Thanks it works, only one thing I want to know why do you use .jstree two times in 'check_node.jstree.jstree'.

Comment: @code_legend I use it more times to check if an element is a leaf like in $('#data').jstree(true).is_leaf or for other reasons. Yes, instead to write this I could, for instance, replace var nod = $('#data').jstree(true).get_node(element); with element.childNodes[1].textContent. I prefer to use the plugin apis, because when the plugin will be updated some lines of code could not work anymore. The only optimization possible is to cache the jstree object in a global variable. I hope this will clarify your doubts.  Thanks, so much.